# Why transparency rgba works only first time

Tags: javascript, dom, version-control, transparency

Transparency should be changed with the rgba, but rgb should not be changed. Only "a" should be changeable. It only works the first time, if I want to change the second time the value is null. Where am I wrong?

```
<select id="elementbackgroundtransparency" onchange="ElementBackgroundTransparency()">
    <option value="1">1</option>                 
    <option value="0.1">0.1</option>                 
    <option value="0.2">0.2</option>                
    <option value="0.3">0.3</option>                 
    <option value="0.4">0.4</option>                 
    <option value="0.5">0.5</option>                 
    <option value="0.6">0.6</option>
    <option value="0.7">0.7</option>
    <option value="0.8">0.8</option>
    <option value="0.9">0.9</option>
</select>

<div id="color" style="height:50px;width:50px;background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);"></div>
```

```
function ElementBackgroundTransparency(){
        var t = document.getElementById("elementbackgroundtransparency").value;
        var elem = document.getElementById("color");
        var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

        var rgb = /rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(theCSSprop);
        var r = rgb[1];
        var g = rgb[2];
        var b = rgb[3];
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+""+", "+t+")";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function working fine for the first time because of the value of **A** in **RGBA** **1** which is equal to nothing, therefore your

```
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

**return rgba(255, 0, 0)** which is correct value for your **regex**

But when you change option from dropdown your script **return rgba(255, 0, 0,0.3)** which is **wrong input for your regex** expression.

You have to rectify **theCSSprop** value before passed to regex.

```
function ElementBackgroundTransparency(){
        var t = document.getElementById("elementbackgroundtransparency").value;
        var elem = document.getElementById("color");
        var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
        theCSSprop = theCSSprop.split(",");
        if(theCSSprop.length > 3){
            theCSSprop[0] = theCSSprop[0].replace("a","");
            theCSSprop.splice(-1, 1);
            theCSSprop = theCSSprop.join(",");
            theCSSprop += ")";
        }
        console.log(theCSSprop);
        var rgb = /rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(theCSSprop);
        if(rgb !== null){
            var r = rgb[1];
            var g = rgb[2];
            var b = rgb[3];
            document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+""+", "+t+")";
        }else{
            console.log(rgb,"failed");
        }
}
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hari1_prasad/t0grjw2x/5/)

Comment: I understand where the mistake is. What would be the easiest way to handle this. I try but it doesn't work. In your example, I constantly get:
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Have fixed the code.

Error was coming because Your regex need value in rgb(0,0,0) format But my code send it rgba(255,0,0).

Comment: Thank you. It works great. I would like to ask you another detail. I use clickable multiple divs, so each div has a different value of "a". Clicking on a div I need to insert its value into select (option). How do I get a from every div?

Comment: If your issue is resolved then please mark it as resolved and upvote too.

for your query find the jsFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/hari1_prasad/awk81mt9/

Comment: I mark as solved! Is there an option to insert "a" into the option in pure javiscript in the existing code (no jQuery). Thanks. I hope this will be useful to others as well

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your RGB indexes are not starting at 0